# Piped Input stream is getting locked

Tags: java, stream

I am trying to write the data using the pipe input streams. But from thread dump it looks like there is a lock on pipe input stream.

```
PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos);
FileInputStream fis = null;
GZIPOutputStream gos = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    gos = new GZIPOutputStream(pos);
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1)
        gos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    } catch(Exception e){
        print("Could not read the file");
    }
    finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            gos.close();
        }catch (Exception ie){ 
            printException(ie);
        }
    }
writeObject(pis);
pos.close();
```

writeobj method will simply read from the stream and but read method gets locked.
The thread dumps indicate some wait on pipe input stream.

```
main" prio=10 tid=0x08066000 nid=0x48d2 in Object.wait() [0xb7fd2000..0xb7fd31e8]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xa5c28be8> (a java.io.PipedInputStream)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.awaitSpace(PipedInputStream.java:257)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:215)
    - locked <0xa5c28be8> (a java.io.PipedInputStream)
    at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:132)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish(GZIPOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:146)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

I am not really sure who is locking it up. Read docs to figure out the locking calls. But could not figure out what is going wrong and how to overcome it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working with PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream must be in separate threads.

Read the Javadoc carefully:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

> Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream object by one thread and data is written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread.

Answer (score 7):

PipedInputStream has a small non-expanding buffer. Once the buffer is full, writes to the PipedOutputStream block until the buffered input is read **by a different thread**. You cannot use the two from the same thread, because the write will be waiting for a read that cannot happen.

In your case, you are not reading any of the data until you have written all of it, so the solution is to use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) instead:

1. Write all the data to a ByteArrayOutputStream.
2. When finished, call toByteArray() on the stream to retrieve the byte data.
3. (Optional) Create a ByteArrayInputStream with the byte data to read from it as an InputStream.

Comment: What if the data was in gigabytes? (The app will definitely crash) Streams are created to prevent allocating big memory chunks.

Comment: @HamidVakilian In that case it would indeed crash, but the OP in this case is trying to store the full data in RAM, so I assume they know it will fit.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a filter to intercept slow connections where I need to close DB connections ASAP so I initially used Java pipes but when looked closer at their implementation, it is all synchronized so I ended up creating my own QueueInputStream using a small buffer and Blocking queue to put the buffer in the queue once was full, it is lock free except when for the lock conditions used at LinkedBlockingQueue which with the aid of the small buffer it should be cheap, this class is only intended to be used for a single producer and consumer per instance:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class QueueOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
  private static final byte[] END_SIGNAL=new byte[]{};

  private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue=new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
  private final byte[] buffer;

  private boolean closed=false;
  private int count=0;

  public QueueOutputStream()
  {
    this(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }

  public QueueOutputStream(final int bufferSize)
  {
    if(bufferSize<=0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    this.buffer=new byte[bufferSize];
  }

  private synchronized void flushBuffer()
  {
    if(count>0){
      final byte[] copy=new byte[count];
      System.arraycopy(buffer,0,copy,0,count);
      queue.offer(copy);
      count=0;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(final int b) throws IOException
  {
    if(closed){
      throw new IllegalStateException("Stream is closed");
    }
    if(count>=buffer.length){
      flushBuffer();
    }
    buffer[count++]=(byte)b;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void write(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) throws IOException
  {
    super.write(b,off,len);
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() throws IOException
  {
    flushBuffer();
    queue.offer(END_SIGNAL);
    closed=true;
  }

  public Future<Void> asyncSendToOutputStream(final ExecutorService executor, final OutputStream outputStream)
  {
    return executor.submit(
            new Callable<Void>()
            {
              @Override
              public Void call() throws Exception
              {
                try{
                  byte[] buffer=queue.take();
                  while(buffer!=END_SIGNAL){
                    outputStream.write(buffer);
                    buffer=queue.take();
                  }
                  outputStream.flush();
                } catch(Exception e){
                  close();
                  throw e;
                } finally{
                  outputStream.close();
                }
                return null;
              }
            }
    );
  }
```